# Are functions lost forever?

Tags: transistor

When I first gained a level, I chose Mask() over Bounce(), thinking that I'd have the option to choose Bounce() later. When I levelled up again, I could choose between 2 new options, but not Bounce(). Will I ever be able to gain the functions I didn't choose or will I need to replay the game to try them?

Comment: I don't know how leveling up works exactly but I know at this point I definitely have both Mask and Bounce. So.. there's that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functions not chosen are not lost. You can select them again every few levels, starting with level 5.